# is there a way to make the ":active" selector's style apply to the currently hovered element when the mouse is moving between elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

when you click on one of the 'cButton' elements, the active style will be applied to it but if you hold the mouse button down and then hover over another cButton while still holding, the style will not be applied to it.
I know a way to do it in Javascript but i am trying to do it using pure css.

```css
body{

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

}

.cButton{
  
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
  
}

.cButton:active{

  background: blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
```

Comment: `:active` is a state when the user has clicked on an element `"mousedown"` , and is `:active` until user releases it `"mouseup"`. It's cut and dry -- there's no way to do what you want in CSS. There is a CSS hack that can keep an element `:active` until the page reloads, even after `"mouseup"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in pure CSS. However, here is some JavaScript code that works:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".cButton").forEach(function(ele) {
    ele.onmousedown = function() {
      ele.classList.add("down")
    }
    ele.onmouseover = function(e) {
      if (e.buttons == 1 && e.button == 0) {
        ele.classList.add("down");
      }
    }
    ele.onmouseup = function() {
      ele.classList.remove("down")
    }
    ele.onmouseout = function() {
      ele.classList.remove("down")
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.cButton {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
}

.cButton.down {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
<div class="cButton">
</div>
```

Comment: this is the javascript i currently use there is a proplem in it, sometimes when you click and move the mouse, the 'not allowed' cursor appears and the effect doesn't apply.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: google chrome on Chrome OS
edit: i used user select: none; on the container and the proplem was solved.
should i update the aswer or question? i am new.

Comment: I don't think you need to update anything. I could be wrong, because I'm also new (about a month)

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that that is impossible in pure css. Because you will need a mouse down hover which is not available in css to my knowledge.